# ll command found then not found

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch

I added a new user to a fresh Raspbian Lite install (4.14 2019-04-08, Raspbian Stretch Lite).  On a pi zero, I had direct access and had signed in as the `pi` user.  Via Wifi I had authenticated as the new user.

As the pi user I did:

```
pi@rpizero:~ $ touch hello
```

As the newuser I did:

```
newuser@rpizero:~ $ ll ../pi/
.ansible/      .bash_history  .bash_logout   .bashrc        hello          .profile       
newuser@rpizero:~ $ rm ../pi/hello 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file '../pi/hello'? 
newuser@rpizero:~ $ ll ../pi
-bash: ll: command not found
```

Restarting the device does not help as the `ll` command is still not found.

Why did the `ll` command "get destroyed" when trying to remove the `hello` file?  Very confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no standard `ll` command. Often there is an alias that defines `ll` as `ls -l`.

The output in your question is not from `ls -l`.

It seems that you have typed `ll ../pi/` at the shell prompt and then pressed the <kbd>Tab</kbd> Key. This resulted in the display of the available completions. This is a function of the shell and doesn't check whether a command `ll` is available.

After you removed `../pi/hello`, you didn't use tab completion, you tried to execute the `ll` command/alias.

The most likely explanation is that you never had an alias `ll` defined, and the removal of the file `../pi/hello` had no effect on that.

Comment: I think I must have hit the tab key subconsciously.  Thanks.  I feel like I should delete my question due to serious * facepalm *... what do you think?

Comment: It is a valid question, and others may have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to enable the `ll` command (as RaflFriedl correctly mentioned, it's an alias to the `ls -l` command)...

Open a terminal and make sure you're in your root dir:

`cd ~`

Open the `.bashrc` file. I like using nano.  Use `sudo apt-get install nano` in case it's not installed, then...

`nano .bashrc`

Scroll half way down, where you'll see:

```
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'
```

Remove the `#` that was in front of the `alias ll='ls -l'` line.

To exit nano, Ctrl+X, then 'Y' to confirm the save, then Enter to confirm you're overwriting the file.

Open a new terminal, and you're set! ...Or type `exec bash` in the current terminal to reload the .bashrc file that you just updated.

More details here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/bashrc.md

Comment: And edit `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to include the changes as well, then will new users also get the `ll` command automatically.